# R language:rearrange csv file

Tags: r, csv

I have data loaded via read.csv()
ans looks like something like this.

```
> head(dt)
                                                                             X.U.FEFF.
1 |Gender:Male and suice month:October and reason:Divorce|2010|9.0|
2                                                                         ||2011|10.0|
3                                                                         ||2012|17.0|
4                                                                         ||2013|16.0|
5                                                                         ||2014|16.0|
6                                                                         ||2015|14.0|
```

I need the suicide total number each years depens on the gender.How can I achive this.

Comment: Without further explaination what your data show it will not be possible to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I really understand the question, but if you're just trying to reorder a data frame according to gender, then maybe you should take a look at this [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns)

dt <- dt[with(dt, order(gender)),]